bug na pagina de login react
o meu código ele faz a consulta volta loga e da erro não achei o que é
esse é a chamada
async function ListarByEmailAdmin(email) {
  let sql = `SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email = ?`;
 
    const [rows] = await query(sql, [email]);

    if (!rows || rows.length === 0) {
      return null; // Return null if no user found
    }
    const user = {
      id_admin: rows.id_admin,
      name: rows.name,
      email: rows.email,
      password: rows.password // Include password if allowed by permissions
    };

    return user;
  
}

essa é a funçao que loga e depois da erro
async function ExecuteLogin() {
    setMsg("");
    try {
      const response = await api.post("/admin/login", {
        email,
        password,
      });
      console.log(response);
      if (response.data) {
        localStorage.setItem("sessionToken", response.data.token);
        localStorage.setItem("sessionId", response.data.id_admin);
        localStorage.setItem("sessionEmail", response.data.email);
        localStorage.setItem("sessionName", response.data.name);
        api.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
          "Bearer " + response.data.token;
        navigate("/appointments");
      } else {
        setMsg("erro ao logar");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response?.data.error) {
        setMsg(error.response?.data.error);
      } else {
        setMsg("erro ao logar");
      }
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

nesse caso da esse erro
Restarting 'src/index.js'
servidor rodando na porta :3001..
file:///C:/Users/plugi/OneDrive/%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho/curso%20telegram/framework/react%20native/agendei-api/src/database/mysql.js:14
        reject(new Error(`Erro ao executar a consulta: ${error.message}`));
               ^

Error: Erro ao executar a consulta: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
    at Query.onResult (file:///C:/Users/plugi/OneDrive/%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho/curso%20telegram/framework/react%20native/agendei-api/src/database/mysql.js:14:16)
    at Query.execute (C:\Users\plugi\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\curso telegram\framework\react native\agendei-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:36:14)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (C:\Users\plugi\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\curso telegram\framework\react native\agendei-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:481:34)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\plugi\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\curso telegram\framework\react native\agendei-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\plugi\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\curso telegram\framework\react native\agendei-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\plugi\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\curso telegram\framework\react native\agendei-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)

Node.js v20.11.0
Failed running 'src/index.js'


Na mensagem de erro está descrito o problema You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?'. Não é bug, o sinal interrogação não esta sendo recebendo o valor, provavelmente a função query() que usou não faz o bind, porque não é função correta para esse tipo de função (bind dos valores). Para futuras perguntas é importante ler finalidade do site e fornecer um [mcve] do problema, de forma a facilitar a identificação e servir como referência para futuros visitantes. Agradecemos a compreensão.
